# Submit button is not working when adding prettyPhoto.js in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, prettyphoto

I use Codeigniter to create a website, but i have a problem:

When I add jquery.prettyPhoto.js to my website and click "submit button" it doesn't send to Controller.
I used "var_dump('$_POST')" and the result shows:

- when add jquery.prettyPhoto.js

  array (size=2)

  ```
        '8723daa3c36e2c737becd1af103e0a5d' => string '1' (length=1)
        'a13c4d90f544481e708d0523c6f6d198' => string '2' (length=1)
  ```
- and when I do not add jquery.prettyPhoto.js

  array (size=3)

  ```
       '8723daa3c36e2c737becd1af103e0a5d' => string '1' (length=1)
       'a13c4d90f544481e708d0523c6f6d198' => string '2' (length=1)
       'Update' => string 'Update' (length=6)
  ```
- My header

  public/cus/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" >
- My cotroller

  public function Load_quotation_cus_controls()
          {

  ```
         if($this->input->post('Update'))
          {
              $data=$this->input->post(null);
              var_dump($data);
              exit; 

              if(count($this->cart->contents())>0)
              {
                  $cart=array();
                  foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item)
                  {
                      if($data[$item['rowid']]!=$item['qty'] && $data[$item['rowid']]>=0)
                      {
                          $cart[]=array('rowid'=>$item['rowid'],'qty'=>$data[$item['rowid']]);
                      }
                  }
                  if($cart)
                      $this->cart->update($cart);
              }
          }


          $this->data['path'] = 'Cus/quotation';
          $this->load->view('Cus/layout',$this->data);
      }
  ```
- And my View:

  ```
  <div class="headline_underline margin-bottom24">
                  </div>
  <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <?php
          if(count($this->cart->contents())>0)
          {
              $i=0;
      ?>
       <?php $this->load->helper('form');?>
    <?php echo form_open('','');?>
      <table >
          <tr>
              <td>#</td>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Price</td>
              <td>Qty</td>
              <td>Total</td>
          </tr>
          <?php
              foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item)
              {
                  $i = $i+1;
          ?>

           <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $i?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['id']?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['name']?></td>
              <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $item['price']?></td>
              <td><input 
                  type="number" 
                  value="<?php echo $item['qty']?>" 
                  name="<?php echo $item['rowid']?>" 
                  style="width: 70px; text-align: center;"/> 
              </td>
             <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $item['qty']*$item['price']?></td>
          </tr>
         <?php
              }

         ?>
          <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="quotation" style="text-align: center;" >
           <?php echo form_submit('Update', 'Update');?>
          <a href="#" class="margin-left24 green">Send quotation</a>
          <a href="#" class="margin-left24">Delete</a>
          </td>
          </tr>

      </table>

      <?php  ?>
  </div>
  <?php
  }
   else
          {
              echo '<h2 align="center">Bạn chưa chọn sản phẩm để báo giá.</h2>';
          }
         ?>


   <div class="clear"></div>
  ```

Please give me some advises for this case. Thanks very much.

Comment: where have you opened the form??

Comment: Hi @NiranjanNRaju, I copied not enought my code..sr. But this form work normal until i add jquery.prettyPhoto.js.

Comment: Please add complete form... Then only we can help you..

Comment: Thanks @NiranjanNRaju, I have added complete form.

Comment: In form open, you have not specified the controller name.

Comment: ok, I try this but it still not working. The form and all input send exactly controller except the `<input type="submit" name="Update"/>`  not send?

Comment: Give value to submit button...

Comment: It still not woking... :(

Comment: Where is your `form_close()`??